# LevelUp retrieves (gets) string data as Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, leveldb, leveldown, levelup

I am saving a hex string using levelup in a Node.js application.

```
const levelUP = require('levelup');
const levelDown = require('leveldown');

const db = levelUP(levelDown('./names.db'), (er, up) => {
   if (er) { return; }
   let id  = 'id3';
   let hex = '5aeb8824b68cd4a3aa4f2fd0cd8';
    console.log('Saving:', hex);
    db.put(id, hex).then(() => {
        db.get(id).then(value => {
            console.log('Loaded:', value);
        });
    });
});
```

The value in `put` is of course a string, and even `typeof hex` returns `string`. The value returned from the get is an Uint8Array. The values of those bytes are correct I guess, if the hex was treated as a simple string (rather than hex encoded byte array). It makes no sense however as the documentation states otherwise. What could be wrong?